# Similar to Euler 110

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This problem is similar to Euler Problem 110 - 
Find all possible (x,y) such that for a given N:

1/x + 1/y = 1/N

The solution for this problem I found out was finding all the prime factors of N^2 and halving it for finding unique solutions to the problem.

The new problem is

1/x + 1/y = 1/N!

(N factorial)

The value of N may be very large(as large as 10^6). Any idea how should I proceed on this?

Comment: This is not homework. Its a question from interviewstreet.com

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the factorization of `n!` instead of doing the multiplications, this should be easy for you -- after finding the factorization, it's the same code as you had before.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more.. :)

Comment: No, you should be able to figure it out from here.